# OpenAI GPT-3 API error: "Invalid URL (POST /v1/chat/completions)"

Tags: node.js, openai-api, gpt-3

Here is my code snippet:

```
const { Configuration, OpenAI, OpenAIApi } = require ("openai");
const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: 'MY KEY'
})

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration)

async function start() {
    const response = await openai.createChatCompletion({
        model:"text-davinci-003",
        prompt: "Write a 90 word essay about Family Guy",
        temperature: 0,
        max_tokens: 1000
    })

    console.log(response.data.choices[0].text)
}

start()
```

when I run: `node index`

I run into this issue:

```
data: {
      error: {
        message: 'Invalid URL (POST /v1/chat/completions)',
        type: 'invalid_request_error',
        param: null,
        code: null
      }
    }
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Node.js v18.15.0

I've looked all over the internet and tried some solutions but nothing seems to work. Please help!

Usually others have some link attached to their code when I look up this problem online. Very much a beginner at this stuff so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: The OpenAI API isn't very good with its response statuses. You need to check the actual response text. Try `start().catch((err) => console.error(err.response?.data ?? err.toJSON?.() ?? err))` to get more details

Comment: the output of  "" start().catch((err) => console.error(err.response?.data ?? err.toJSON?.() ?? err)) "" seems to be the same I get: PS C:\Users\Dasa\Desktop\Node-ChatGPT> node index
{
  error: {
    message: 'Invalid URL (POST /v1/chat/completions)',
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
    param: null,
    code: null
  }
}

Comment: Could you add a label to that so that it's clear you're actually running the right code... `console.error("start failed", err.response?.data ?? err.toJSON.?() ?? err)`. Please also [edit] your question to show the current state of your code and any changes to the error message

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR: Treat the `text-davinci-003` as a GPT-3 model (i.e., [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api)). See the code under OPTION 1.**

### Introduction

At first glance, as someone who's been using the OpenAI API for the past few months, I thought the answer was straight and simple if you read the official OpenAI documentation. Well, I read the documentation once again, and now I understand why you're confused.

#### Confusion number 1

You want to use the `text-davinci-003` model. This model is originally from the GPT-3 model family. But if you take a look at the [OpenAI models overview](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/overview) and click [GPT-3](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3), you won't find `text-davinci-003` listed as a GPT-3 model. This is unexpected.

[image: Screenshot 1]

#### Confusion number 2

Moreover, the `text-davinci-003` is listed as a [GPT-3.5](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3-5) model.

[image: Screenshot 2]

#### Confusion number 3

As if this isn't confusing enough, if you take a look at the [OpenAI model endpoint compatibility](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/model-endpoint-compatibility), you'll find the `text-davinci-003` listed under the `/v1/completions` endpoint. This API endpoint is used for the GPT-3 model family.

[image: Screenshot 3]

### Wait, what?

The `text-davinci-003` isn't listed as a GPT-3 model (i.e., [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api)). It's listed as a GPT-3.5 model (i.e., [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api)) but is compatible with the GPT-3 API endpoint. This doesn't make any sense.

### Test

Either the `text-davinci-003` could be treated as a GPT-3 model or a GPT-3.5 model, or perhaps both? Let's make a test.

*Note: OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4` was [released](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/releases/tag/v4.0.0) on August 16, 2023, and is a complete rewrite of the SDK. The code below differs depending on the version you currently have. See the `v3` to `v4` [migration guide](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/discussions/217).*

###### OPTION 1: Treat the `text-davinci-003` as a GPT-3 model --> IT WORKS ✓

If you treat the `text-davinci-003` as a GPT-3 model, then run `test-1.js`, and the OpenAI will return the following completion:

> This is indeed a test

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`:

**test-1.js**

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

async function getCompletionFromOpenAI() {
  const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
    model: 'text-davinci-003',
    prompt: 'Say this is a test',
    max_tokens: 7,
    temperature: 0,
  });

  console.log(completion.data.choices[0].text);
}

getCompletionFromOpenAI();
```

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`:

**test-1.js**

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

async function getCompletionFromOpenAI() {
  const completion = await openai.completions.create({
    model: 'text-davinci-003',
    prompt: 'Say this is a test',
    max_tokens: 7,
    temperature: 0,
  });

  console.log(completion.choices[0].text);
}

getCompletionFromOpenAI();
```

###### OPTION 2: Treat the `text-davinci-003` as a GPT-3.5 model --> IT DOESN'T WORK ✗

If you treat the `text-davinci-003` as a GPT-3.5 model, then run `test-2.js`, and the OpenAI will return the following error:

```
data: {
  error: {
    message: 'Invalid URL (POST /v1/chat/completions)',
    type: 'invalid_request_error',
    param: null,
    code: null
  }
}
```

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v3`:

**test-2.js**

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

async function getChatCompletionFromOpenAI() {
  const chatCompletion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
    model: 'text-davinci-003',
    messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Hello!' }],
    temperature: 0,
  });

  console.log(chatCompletion.data.choices[0].message.content);
}

getChatCompletionFromOpenAI();
```

• If you have the OpenAI NodeJS SDK `v4`:

**test-2.js**

```
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

async function getChatCompletionFromOpenAI() {
  const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    messages: [{role: 'user', content: 'Hello!'}],
    temperature: 0,
  });

  console.log(chatCompletion.choices[0].message.content);
}

getChatCompletionFromOpenAI();
```

### Conclusion

Treat the `text-davinci-003` as a GPT-3 model. See the code under OPTION 1.

Comment: Thanks! That solution is so simple and I feel dumb lol but the documentation is kinda a pain to follow and your explanation of completions vs chat completions was super helpful!

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing two capabilities of OpenAI API.

You can either create one-time completion from a prompt, what they call [Completions](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create), or you can create completion from a discussion between an agent an a user, what they call [ChatCompletion](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create).

Depending on which one you want to use the parameters are not the same.

In the first case it should be

```js
const response = await openai. createCompletion({
        model:"text-davinci-003",
        prompt: "Write a 90 word essay about Family Guy",
        temperature: 0,
        max_tokens: 1000
    })
```

and in the other case, you need to specify messages, and the role.

```js
const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages: [{role: "user", content: "Hello world"}],
});
```

Take a look at the API documentation to understand the difference between the two different APIs.